# Does nginx really need dac_override in its AppArmor policy?

Tags: nginx, apparmor

I am building an AppArmor policy for `nginx` in Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot make it work without enabling the `dac_override` capability.

Does `nginx` really need this enabled or is there some way to work around it? Overriding all discretionary access control looks risky, but perhaps it's common within the AppArmor constraints.

`nginx` runs fine unconfined, so I don't think there is a permission issue, but I'm new to AppArmor so I may be wrong.

Comment: You should be looking at the specific calls which are failing.

Comment: `nginx` fails to boot because of log file permissions, but I fail to see why it works unconfined.

Comment: I personally think this is a bug, I opened a bug report explaining how to run nginx without dac_override. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819751

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default file permissions for nginx logs in Ubuntu are `rw-r-----`. These files are owned by `www-admin:adm`.

`nginx` starts under user `root`, which has `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` capability by default (remember that `root` can read and write to any file in the system) but once AppArmor confinement kicks in, the process loses that capability even though it runs as `root`, so the master nginx process cannot open the log files.

The solution is either changing the permissions so that `root` can also write to these files, or adding the `dac_override` capability to the AppArmor nginx profile.

Answer (score 3):

Further to your own answer above, you could perhaps mitigate the issue of perceived excessively wide access by using a "[restricted dac_override](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/TechnicalDoc#capabilities)" policy:

```
capability dac_override {
    /var/log/nginx* rw,
}
```

[According to the docs](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#interaction-of-capability-rules-with-other-rules), it should also be noted that even an unrestricted `dac_override` policy doesn't provide an unrestricted access across the entire filesystem such that a regular, unconfined, `root` process would enjoy:

> "... to be able to access file that is not owned by someone else the task must have the dac_overide capability and the profile must contain both a file access rule and capability dac_override."

Comment: The links are broken here...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know; I have replaced the links with an archived version - until the documentation gets migrated to Gitlab (hopefully)

Comment: Thanks. Docs are on GitLab now. (I updated the links in your post)